# ABTableViewCell and adding an image

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4

For a view in my iPhone application, I am using a subclass of the `ABTableViewCell` (https://github.com/enormego/ABTableViewCell). It's a fairly simple cell, but I wanted to use this for the scrolling speed I need, because a lot of them can in the table at once.

Here is the header of the file:

```
@interface WHUserTableViewCell : ABTableViewCell {

    NSString* Name;
    NSString* DetailsText;
    UIImage*  UserImage;

}

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString* Name;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString* DetailsText;
@property (nonatomic, copy) UIImage* UserImage;
```

I know that by using 'copy' on an image, I am only supporting iOS 4.2 and up, but that is something I might fix later.

I follow the way AteBits uses this cell, by creating custom set methods for the properties, like this:

```
- (void) setUserImage:(UIImage *) userImage
{
    [UserImage release];
    UserImage = [userImage copy];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void) setName:(NSString *) name
{
    [Name release];
    Name = [name copy];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void) setDetailsText:(NSString *) detailsText
{
    [DetailsText release];
    DetailsText = [detailsText copy];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

The images that are assigned to the 'UserImage' property, are coming from a Singleton class, which provides caching and downloading of the images. So that class should be the 'owner' of the images.

There is only one problem, once the cell deallocs, and I release all the properties the application crashes on the `[UserImage release]` line, here's my dealloc method:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];

    [UserImage release];
    [Name release];
    [DetailsText release];
}
```

This cell uses custom drawing, just like AteBits explains in his famous blog post about this. What is the correct and fastest way to handle images for this. I would like to continue using my singleton caching/downloading class to handle images, but I don't think that is the source of the problem, since I am copying the image objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[super dealloc];` should be the last line of `- (void)dealloc`.

Related: [Why do I have to call super -dealloc last, and not first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/909856/why-do-i-have-to-call-super-dealloc-last-and-not-first)

Comment: Yup, somehow I completely overlooked this. I moved it around and it works now. Not sure how I could miss this :( Thanks for your help and such an obvious question/answer.