# debug error EXC_BAD_ACCESS in main.m

Tags: xcode, xcode4, ios4, uitabbarcontroller, xcode4.2

bar controller, 
My project name is "DebtDevV1", which switch between view "AddDebtor" and "Debtor". I built it based on the "tabbed based application".

When i press "DebtorViewController", it stopped at below coding in main.m
Error message:

> Program received signal "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"

When i put my cursor on DebtDevV1AppDelegate, it shows `"Out of Scope"`.

Below is the main.m:

```
#import "DebtDevV1AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([DebtDevV1AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

Below is the DebtDevV1AppDelegate.m

```
#import "DebtDevV1AppDelegate.h"
#import "AddDebtorViewController.h"
#import "DebtorViewController.h"

@implementation DebtDevV1AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize tabBarController = _tabBarController;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UIViewController *viewController1 = [[[AddDebtorViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AddDebtorViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    UIViewController *viewController2 = [[[DebtorViewController alloc] initWithNibName:
    @"DebtorViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    self.tabBarController = [[[UITabBarController alloc] init] autorelease];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1, viewController2, nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Does anyone come across or have idea on above error?
Thanks!

Comment: Use ARC and remove `autorelease`.

Comment: What does you dealloc methods look like?

Comment: sorry, may I know what is ARC? Also you mean i need to remove all [...autorelease] code? or which autorelease to remove?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the same problem I had a few months ago. Check your dealloc methods. Make sure `[super dealloc]` is the last call you make in the dealloc method. [EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash when switching back and forth between views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7624051/exc-bad-access-crash-when-switching-back-and-forth-between-views)

Comment: should i have dealloc methods in the 2 .m files in the 2 views also? currently i only have dealloc method in AppDelegate.m file