# memory leak on dealloc

Tags: iphone, memory-management, memory-leaks

I am new to iPhone Development.
I have taken UIView,UIImageView,UIScrollView etc in my NIB File.
My question is that can i remove all that views from SuperView ?
For Example:`

```
-(void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
    [imageView removeFromSuperview];
    [View1 removeFromSuperview];
    [View2 removeFromSuperview];      
    [ScrollView removeFromSuperview];

    [imageView release];
    [View1 release];
    [View2 release];
    [ScrollView release];

    imageView = nil;
    View1 = nil;
    View2 = nil;
    ScrollView = nil;
}
```

please help me.Thanking you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to remove those subviews from superview, since anyhow you are going to release the superview itself.

You can make the `dealloc` as follows.

```
-(void)dealloc{

    [imageView release];
    [View1 release];
    [View2 release];
    [ScrollView release];

    imageView = nil;
    View1 = nil;
    View2 = nil;
    ScrollView = nil;

    [super dealloc];
}
```

Note that `[super dealloc]` is at the end ([More info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/909856/why-do-i-have-to-call-super-dealloc-last-and-not-first)).

Comment: thank you aadhira...but why should i write [super dealloc] at the end?i mean if i write [super dealloc] at the top then what will happen and if i write at the end then what will happen?

Answer (score 4):

You need to call `[super dealloc];` as the very *last* thing, not *first*. That's because `[super dealloc]` cleans up your object, and accessing instance variables afterwards is undefined behavior: anything can happen. For example, `[super dealloc]` could set all instance variables to `nil`, in which case the following `release` calls simply have no effect (and thus cause leaks). Also, there's no need to set the instance variables to `nil` since you're not going to use them anyway. So all you need is:

```
-(void)dealloc
{
    [imageView release];
    [View1 release];
    [View2 release];
    [ScrollView release];

    [super dealloc];
}
```

A few more notes: the `removeFromSuperview` calls are harmless but unnecessary, this is implicitly done by `[super dealloc]`. And you should stick to Apples naming conventions which in your case means you shouldn't start variable names with uppercase letters. So it should be `scrollView` instead of `ScrollView`.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to enable ARC in your projects. You won't need to release these objects anymore; the system will take care of (most of) your memory-management.

You can read more about ARC here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: Turning on ARC in an existing project is a bit overkill if you just want to fix a simple memory leak.

Comment: But it's great if you're starting off on iOS development (like this person is)